# Force browser to reload javascript files

Tags: javascript, html, gruntjs

I tried like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js"?+Date.now()></script>
```

In browser it is showing as it is. 
I want to add some timestamp to each js files. 
i.e.,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js"?+5671836294></script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a URL get request. The src should ONLY point to a file.

Comment: can you elaborate a little more? what do you want to avoid with this? cache?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Please, do some research before asking on Stack Overflow, as detailed in [ask], under the heading "Search, and research".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force browser to reload cached CSS/JS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/how-to-force-browser-to-reload-cached-css-js-files)

Answer (score 3):

You can't randomly stick JavaScript anywhere you like in HTML.

When you are in the middle of an HTML start tag you can either:

- End the tag with `>`
- Write an attribute

JavaScript does not belong there.

If you want to generate an HTML attribute value dynamically when the element is created, then you must create the **entire element** with JavaScript.

e.g.

```
<script>
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = "myfile.js"?+Date.now();
    document.head.appendChild(s);
</script>
```

… but you'd probably be better of solving this problem by [properly configuring your HTTP headers](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) for the script instead.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the page or rewrite the script tag and append it to the bottom of the body.

But once a page is loaded, it is loaded. You have to redeclare to overwrite.